# HTML video tag: rounded corners are pixelated

Tags: html, css, html5-video

I am trying to show a video with rounded corners, but on the bottom corners, it is pixalated (as showen on the attached screenshot).

This is the HTML code I have tried:

```
<div class="container1">
      <video src="Videos/Film 1.mp4" poster="Thumbnails/Film 1.jpg" class="video1" id="video1" onclick="controlsChangeVideo1()"></video>
</div>
```

And this the CSS:

```
.container1 {
    margin-left: 50px;
    margin-right: 425px;
    margin-top: 50px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this code for a more precise result.

---

**HTML**
`

```
<div class="container1">
    <div class="video-container">
        <video src="Videos/Film 1.mp4" poster="Thumbnails/Film 1.jpg" class="video1" id="video1" onclick="controlsChangeVideo1"></video>
    </div>
</div>
```

`

---

**CSS**
`

```
.container1 {
    margin-left: 50px;
    margin-right: 425px;
    margin-top: 50px;
}

.video-container {
    border-radius: 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.video1 {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    border-radius: 20px; /* Adjust this value as needed */
}
```

`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

This is because the size of the container does not actually match the size of the video. To make the container match the size of the video player you could use `min-content`.

Also, the rounded corners are actually not "pixelated". If you make the container's border visible, you will notice an extra space below the video. The reason of this is because `video` is defaulted to `inline` display, causing the extra space based on the `line-height`. The suggested way to remove this space is to make the video `display:block`.

[image: Extra padding]

```css
.container1 {
  margin-left: 50px;
  margin-right: 425px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: min-content;
  height: min-content;
}

video {
  display: block;
}
```